# Spring Boot - PoolExhaustedException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I recently rebuild all my Spring 4 Projects with the latest Spring Boot Starter Framework.

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
```

Everything is working fine so far, except that i am experiencing PoolExhaustedException randomly across all my rebuild projects.

The exact exception is:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [http-nio-8080-exec-4] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 20 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:20000].
```

The last exception i received was from a controller which is downloading a document from my database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDocument/{value}/{text}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void get(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String value, @PathVariable String text){
      try {
          Document ufile = documentService.getDocumentByID(Integer.parseInt(value));

          response.setContentType(ufile.getType());
          response.setContentLength(ufile.getContent().length);
          FileCopyUtils.copy(ufile.getContent(), response.getOutputStream());

      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
public Document getDocumentByID(int id) {
    Document r = this.documentDAO.getDocumentByID(id);
    return r;
}
```

DAO:

```
@Transactional
public Document getDocumentByID(int id)
{
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();      
    Document p = (Document) session.load(Document.class, new Integer(id));
    return p;
}
```

I already tried to annotate the Controller with @Transactional which temporarily solved the problem, but led to other transactional errors so i had to remove it.

I also tried to increase the pool via project.properties too 100 which only delayed the problem but didn't solve it.

project.properties

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the properties with these names have any effect.

I'd also try to put a breakpoint and inspect the Tomcat DataSource directly to view the values to be convinced (can be easily autowired in a test).

Looking at the `Spring Boot` [Tomcat Datasource Configuration Tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/TomcatDataSourceConfigurationTests.java) I see some interesting options like [minEvictableIdleTimeMillis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/TomcatDataSourceConfigurationTests.java#L76), [timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/TomcatDataSourceConfigurationTests.java#L75) and maxWait all prefixed with `spring.datasource.tomcat.`, so give them a try.

Comment: I guess my main problem is tomcat or hibernate not closing my autowired session properly, but i will check that out.